# Calculating and Displaying Confidence Intervals of Means

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, confidence-interval

I've currently got a graph that displays the mean of the distance per group, in R. However I am struggling to add the confidence intervals in and display them on the graph.

My code is:

```
TeamMeans<- read.csv(file = file.choose())
teamM=TeamMeans
graph6<-ggplot(aes(x=Team, y=Mean), data=teamM)
  + geom_point()
  + geom_smooth(size = 2, alpha = 0.35)
  + aes(group=1) 
  + labs(x= 'Team Names', y= 'Mean', title= 'Means of Throws Per Team') 
  + coord_flip() 
graph6
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_errorbar`. See`http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_errorbar.html

Comment: @user3555044 Could you provide some data?

Answer (score 0):

As `team` is a factor variable, using a barplot with errorbars is more appropriate for plotting a summary of this kind of data.

```
# creating some data
set.seed(12)
teamM <- data.frame(team=rep(LETTERS[1:5],length=100), distance=rnorm(100,4,1))

# creating the plot
ggplot(teamM, aes(x=team, y=distance, fill=team)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", width=0.3) +
  labs(x= 'Team Names', y= 'Mean', title= 'Means of Throws Per Team\n') +
  theme_bw()
```

the result:

[image]

Another way of displaying a summary of the data is using a `boxplot`:

```
ggplot(teamM, aes(x=team, y=distance, fill=team)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(x= 'Team Names', y= 'Mean', title= 'Means of Throws Per Team\n') +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]